# How to build regex to match string in quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

After such a long time working with JavaScript, I would know how to build regex but that is so tedious to learn ^^

I need a regex that can match one string in quotes.

For example: `"CC1AD849"`

- the length is always 8
- it's only uppercase letters and mixed with 0-9 and A-Z
- it needs to find a string with at least 2 numbers and 2 letters
  so it don't match `"AAAAAAAA"` or `"12345678"`

so far i got `/"[A-Z0-9]{8}"/` but the last criteria is not meet...
(it finds lots of words that I'm not interested in)

Comment: Do the letters and digits need to be consecutive? Is `AA123456` a match as well as `A123456A` (likewise, is it the same for `AAAAAA12` and `1AAAAAA2`?)

Comment: it don't have to be consecutive `AAAAAA12` and `1AAAAAA2` are both valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
/"(?=(?:[0-9]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:[A-Z]*[0-9]){2})[A-Z0-9]{8}"/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4p6p1/1)

**Details**

- `"` - a double quote
- `(?=(?:[0-9]*[A-Z]){2})` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires two sequences of any 0+ digits followed with a single uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=(?:[A-Z]*[0-9]){2})` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires two sequences of any 0+ uppercase ASCII letters followed with a single digit
- `[A-Z0-9]{8}` - 8 uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `"` - a double quote.

JS demo:

```js
var s = '"CC1AD849" "11111112" "CDFGHJYF"';
console.log(s.match(/"(?=(?:[0-9]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:[A-Z]*[0-9]){2})[A-Z0-9]{8}"/g));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation also, It works... but unfortunately I didn't find what I was looking for. The id must probably come from some api or something.

Comment: @Endless What do you mean? If you need further adjustment, please let know what your real life input looks like and what you need to get from it.

Comment: Trying to reverse engineer some code. So I'm search lots of file for a receiver identification. but it probably not included in the codebase. Don't think further adjustment is needed

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
/^(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})[A-Z0-9]{8}$/
```

An explanation:

```
/^
  (?=(.*\d){2})     // uses lookahead (?=) and says the password must contain at least 2 digits
  (?=(.*[A-Z]){2})  // uses lookahead (?=) and says the password must contain at least 2 Upper Case chars
  [A-Z0-9]{8}       // should contain strictly 8 from the mentioned characters
$/
```